# Filtering With Uppercase or Lowercase in NGXS Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, ngxs

I have a problem in filtering/searching, it should match the exact lowercase or uppercase of the string. How would i able to search/filter regardless of the lowercase/uppercase.Please see this link [CLICK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-searching?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
@Selector()
  static nameFilter(name: string ){
    return createSelector([AppState], (state: any)=> {
      return state.app.people.filter(
        (p: People) => {
          console.log(p, name)
          if (name){
            if (p.name.includes(name)) {return p}
          } 
          else return p
        }
      ).sort(
        (a: any, b: any) => {
          return a - b
        }
      )
    })
  }
```

Comment: It seems the demo you provided does indeed match case sensitive input. I got a result with "mark", but not with "Mark"

Comment: if (p.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())) {return p}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert all to lowerCase before filtering:

```
if (p.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())) {return p}
```

Comment: I thought so as well, but the algorithm already does that. And OP writes: `How would i able to search/filter regardless of the lowercase/uppercase`. Regardless is the key word, so I thought OP wanted to filter without caring about case sensitive letters